# how remove sub path from csv file

Tags: python, csv

in 'id_path' in CSV file i want remove subpath from it such as

[dataframe of csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qr1j7.png)

i want remove all path before the image file name

./input/skin-cancer-malignant-vs-benign/data/test/benign/454.jpg

./input/skin-cancer-malignant-vs-benign/data/test/benign/90.jpg

./input/skin-cancer-malignant-vs-benign/data/test/benign/147.jpg

./input/skin-cancer-malignant-vs-benign/data/test/malignant/771.jpg

./input/skin-cancer-malignant-vs-benign/data/test/malignant/208.jpg

./input/skin-cancer-malignant-vs-benign/data/test/malignant/1383.jpg

./input/skin-cancer-malignant-vs-benign/data/test/malignant/1354.jpg

the output should be

454.jpg

90.jpg

147.jpg

771.jpg

208.jpg

1383.jpg

1354.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rsplit()` splits the data from the right side of the string and `1` is way of saying python to stop after first split.

```py
txt = "./input/skin-cancer-malignant-vs-benign/data/test/benign/454.jpg"
x = txt.rsplit("/",1)
#your answer
print(x[1])
```

on your dataframe you could do something like:

```py
train_df['id_path'] = train_df['id_path'].apply(lambda x: x.rsplit('/',1)[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `str.replace`:

```py
df["filename"] = df["path"].str.replace(r'^.*/', '')
```

We could also use `str.extract` here:

```py
df["filename"] = df["path"].str.extract(r'([^/]+\.\S+$)')
```

Comment: I don't python.  Is this a unique question or should it be closed?